# On page closure, trigger logout function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make it so when a user closes my web app or navigates away from it, that the logout function is automatically triggered.

I've tried various mechanisms but this would seem to be the most logical:

```
window.addEventListener("unload",logout());
```

However this just causes the page to trigger the logout function when it loads and it keeps cycling. Is there a way to to trigger the logout function when the user closes the tab, navigates away from the page or closes the browser? I'm NOT worried about the pop up side of it, I just want to be able to trigger the logout function.

For clarity, here is my logout function:

```
function logout() {
  document.body.style.cursor = "wait";
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.withCredentials = true;

  xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
      document.body.innerHTML = 'User logged out';
      document.body.style.cursor = "initial";
      location.reload();
    }
  });

  xhr.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:7071/logout");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authToken);


  xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Why though? What does logging out change?

Comment: I think your logout function takes too long to be executed in the small time window you have when closing the tab, reloading the page, etc. Therefore, you're not seeing any results.

Comment: @JonasWilms it kills the session on the server side. It's not essential to security but it seems like a reasonably good idea, given that users have a tendency to close pages instead of using the proper log out button.

Comment: @CodeF0x ah okay, is there any way around the issue of it taking too long?

Comment: Maybe you can add something on the server side that kills the session after the corresponding user was inactive for too long? So either the user was afk for too long or simply closed the page without logging out, but in both cases they will get logged out.

Comment: Thanks CodeF0x but the issue with that is that the server side is semi-stateless as it an Azure Function written in Node.Every time the user connects to the server after authentication, they must provide an authorization token in the header which is encrypted and contains, among other things, a session Id which is verified against the DB. To enact this, I would need to create a new time triggered function that went through all the logged in users and removed the session Id for those that are too old. This would be expensive for Azure Functions and Azure Cosmos DB.

Comment: @pixie what happens if the clients network goes down? Or ... Instead of looging out explicitly you should time out sessions after some time, just as everyone else does. You could just store a `lastSeen` time, and reject a session if `lastSeen > Date.now() + timeoutTime`, that wouldn't need a background task

Comment: @JonasWilms well the Web App uses AJAX calls so it's not a persistent connection between the client and the server. Essentially in the authorization token, it does encrypt a time var in there and the user session expires after 30 mins. It won't check the Session Id if the request is within 15 seconds of the last verified connection, which does fulfill this but I'm trying to reduce the potential of replay attacks (i.e. replay the message within 15 seconds and you've got an authenticated session)

Comment: @pixie I don't think that logging out will tackle that problem, the only thing you can do is to properly set up tls (to reduce the attacking vector to the users device)

Comment: I think you maybe right Jonas. I'm trying to balance the operational cost of hitting the DB multiple times with each server request against security of the application. However as it is designed to be run on enterprise networks then I guess I will have to trust my clients have set their networks up correctly (and if they haven't they will have more problems than my app being accessible). The auth token is encrypted using AES-256-GCM and then the traffic is encrypted via HTTPS, I think I might be worrying over a very small thing

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, do not invoke the `logout` function with `()`:

```
window.addEventListener("unload", logout);
```

or

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", logout);
```

Comment: How about `beforeunload`?

Comment: Same result I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking your function. Try without the parantheses:
`window.addEventListener('unload', logout);`

---

Alternatively, you can also overwrite `window.onbeforeunload`:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = logout;
function logout() {
  console.log("LOGGED OUT");
}
```

```html
<a href="example.com">just some link to test</a>
```

(When clicking on "Run code snippet" and then reloading this page, the `console.log` is longer visible, at least for me.)

Comment: Thank you, again it stops the looping but it isn't actually running the logout function when I refresh the page or close the tab. I'll add my logout function code to my question for clarity